# Green function for a second-order elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, elliptic-operators, fundamental-solution

Let $L = L^*$ be a second-order elliptic PDE with smooth and bounded coefficients in some bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$, $d \geq 3$, with smooth boundary. Let $G(x,y)$ be a Green function for the Dirichlet problem with the following properties:
$$
    L_x G(x,y) = \delta_y(x), \\
    G(x,y) = 0 \; \text{if $x \in \partial \Omega$ or $y \in \partial \Omega$}, \\
    |G(x,y)| \leq C|x-y|^{2-d}, \\
    |\nabla_x G(x,y)| \leq C|x-y|^{1-d}, \\
    |\nabla^2_x G(x,y)| \leq C|x-y|^{-d},\\
    \text{$G(x,y)$ is $C^\infty$ away from the diagonal in $\overline \Omega \times \overline \Omega$.}
$$
*Question:* Is it possible to deduce from these formulas that for any $\varphi \in C^2(\overline \Omega)$ satisfying $L\varphi = 0$ in $\Omega$ we have
$$
 \varphi(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial \nu_y}\varphi(y) \, dy,
$$
where $\nu_y$ is the unit exterior normal, for all $x \in \overline \Omega$? (for $x \in \partial \Omega$ I mean the limit from $\Omega$).

I hope the answer is positive. In M. Taylor's book "Partial Differential Equations, II", p. 36 the author considers a fundamental solution to the Laplace equation in a bounded region on a manifold (I write "a solution" because I don't see there any specification of boundary values for this solution). Any such solution has a form
$$
   E(x,y) \sim C(d)|x-y|^{2-d} + \cdots,
$$
and this allows the author to show that for the single and double layer potentials, defined for a function $f \in C(\partial \Omega)$ as
$$
   Sf(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} E(x,y) f(y) \, dy, \\
   Df(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial E(x,y)}{\partial \nu_y} f(y) \, dy,
$$
we have
$$
   Sf(x-0) = Sf(x), \quad x \in \partial \Omega, \\
   Df(x-0) = \frac 1 2 f(x) + Df(x), \quad x \in \partial \Omega,
$$
where $x-0$ means a limit from $\Omega$. Now if we specify additionally that $E(x,y) = 0$ for $x \in \partial \Omega$ or $y \in \partial \Omega$ we must have by the property of the Green function for the Dirichlet problem that 
$$
Df(x) = \frac 1 2 f(x), \quad x \in \partial \Omega,
$$
in order to have $Df(x-0) = f(x)$, $x \in \partial \Omega$. Does this equality really hold?